# Failed to fetch security.debian.org on Windows host

Tags: windows-7, security, virtualbox, debian, ipv6

I am using 64-bit Debian 6.0 (*squeeze*) from a Windows 7 64-bit VirtualBox host, but I'm unable to successfully `ping security.debian.org` from both the guest *or* the Windows host. E.g., from the VirtualBox guest, as root:

```
root@debian~# apt-get update
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_NZ
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze-updates Release.gpg     
Ign http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en       
Ign http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en_NZ    
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze Release                 
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze-updates Release                           
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze/main Sources                              
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex            
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Hit http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_NZ
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done          
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_NZ.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Actually, VirtualBox aside, I can't navigate my Windows browsers to most of Debian's websites, including http://security.debian.org/. My laptop connects to a regular home network wireless router, with the following network connection details:

```
c:\>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b8ab:5283:7563:56b9%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.103
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6c85:d4c8:a632:1a17%38
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B8D0B539-DEBD-44FA-A083-408C923B6842}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{10ECE2A8-F684-4D23-8E4E-D1CD154842CB}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BADD3B76-F50E-4452-922D-C30F6A04E27F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{96FB53A6-3CBB-422D-B27B-EA9175F8EF99}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {FB46FC81-EEE3-4D64-BD27-77A8E0C25C7D}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:34bc:2a99:86b6:92e
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34bc:2a99:86b6:92e%14
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E9EE8EC1-E630-4680-B111-4A56D298A88B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

And my guest has configuration:

```
root@dev:~# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:32:ae:42  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe32:ae42/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:317629 (310.1 KiB)  TX bytes:458447 (447.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:40217 (39.2 KiB)  TX bytes:40217 (39.2 KiB)
```

From what I've read regarding issues connecting to security.debian.org, IPv6 can get in the way, and that you need to change the preference to IPv4 somehow. I've tried modifying `/etc/gai.conf` to use `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` (as [suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method)), but no luck. Do I need to disable IPv6 from the Windows host? Is there an alternative IPv4 navigable website for security.debian.org? Anything else worth trying?

Comment: Are you able to ping other websites?

Comment: It is a net install, so almost the whole web is there, obviously not http://security.debian.org

Comment: At http://test-ipv6.com/ both host and guest have same results 10/10 for IPv4 and 0/10 for IPv6 stability and readiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to be having results with a hack from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9941/8076) that adds to `/etc/hosts`:

```
195.20.242.89 security.debian.org
```

And who is 195.20.242.89 (aka http://wieck.debian.org/)?

> Welcome to wieck! ... She does stuff.

at least she turns out to be described as a [security mirror](http://db.debian.org/machines.cgi?host=wieck).

(Note: I'd love to accept a better answer than my own.)